# How to restore a deleted folder from HDFS

Tags: hdfs

I deleted a folder from HDFS, I found it under

```
/user/hdfs/.Trash/Current/
```

but I can't restore it. I looked in the forum but I don't find the good solution.
Please someone have a solution I can help me how can I restore my folder in the best directory ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Did you try `cp` or `mv`? e.g.,

```
hdfs dfs -cp -r /user/hdfs/.Trash/Current/ /hdfs/Current
```

Answer (score 5):

Before moving back your directory, you should locate where your file is in:

```
hadoop fs -lsr /user/<user-name>/.Trash | less
```

Eg, you may found:

```
-rw-r--r--   3 <user-name> supergroup     111792 2020-06-28 13:17 /user/<user-name>/.Trash/200630163000/user/<user-name>/dir1/dir2/file
```

If `dir1` is your deleted dir, move it back:

```
hadoop fs -mv /user/<user-name>/.Trash/200630163000/user/<user-name>/dir1 <destination>
```

Answer (score 2):

To move from

```
/user/hdfs/.Trash/Current/<your file>
```

Use the -cp command, like this

```
hdfs dfs -cp /user/hdfs/.Trash/Current/<your file> <destination>
```

Also you will find that your dir/file name is changed you can change it back to whatever you want by using '-mv' like this:

```
hdfs dfs -mv <Your deleted filename with its path> <Your new filename with its path>
```

Example:

```
hdfs dfs -mv /hdfs/weirdName1613730289428 /hdfs/normalName
```